# GitHub for Mac pops up "enter your password for the ssh key id_rsa" at startup each time

Tags: git, github, ssh, github-for-mac

It seems to show this dialog two or three times. If I cancel it goes away and I'm still able to commit changes.

How do I prevent it from popping up each time and where do I find my passphrase if I have to reenter it and click "Remember to keychain" (which I've done before but will try again)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the latest version of macOS - 10.12.2/Sierra - this is an easy fix.
Just edit your ~/.ssh/config and enable the UseKeychain option:

```
Host *
UseKeychain yes
```

Save and solved.

Answer (score 3):

If your ssh key has been protected with a passphrase, then you need to run an ssh-agent first, in order to avoid entering said passphrase for every connections.

See [GitHub article "Working with SSH key passphrases"](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#platform-windows).

```
Initializing new SSH agent...
# succeeded
# Enter passphrase for /c/Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa:
# Identity added: /c/Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa (/c/Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa)
# Welcome to Git (version 1.6.0.2-preview20080923)
# 
# Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
# Run 'git help ' to display help for specific commands.
```

If you don't have your passphrase anymore, it is better to re-create a new set of public/private ssh keys (protected, if you want, with a new passphrase), and publish that new public key on your GitHub account.

Comment: I met the same problem but I didn't set up any passphrase at all. There was a passphrase for my old "id_rsa.pub", but I have already generated new key pairs twice and overwrote it twice.

Answer (score 1):

Ricardo's solution is correct for macOS Sierra v. 10.12.2. I still needed to enter the passphrase the first time I ran the `ssh-agent` process, but not again after that. If you are doing this in a terminal instead of a GUI, be sure to either restart your session or reinitialize it with `. ~/.ssh/config`